# mocking a method with parameter as LIST type

Tags: spring, easymock

I want to mock the below mentioned method.

```
public class MockClass {
    public boolean ToBeMocked(Cinput, Coutput, List<CIOChain<Cinput, Coutput>>)
}
```

What should be in place of ?? in below mentioned code ?

```
Easymock.expect(MockClassObject.ToBeMocked(Cinput.class, Coutput.class, ??)).andReturn(true);
```

Comment: I have tried
Easymock.expect(MockClassObject.ToBeMocked(Cinput.class, Coutput.class, List.class)).andReturn(true);

Easymock.expect(MockClassObject.ToBeMocked(Cinput.class, Coutput.class, List<CIOChain<Cinput, Coutput>>)).andReturn(true);

They did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

At the `Class` level, all `List` interfaces are the same regardless of the generic type, due to type erasure; they are only different at compile time.

So it's just `List.class` in place of `??`.

That is,

```
Easymock.expect(MockClassObject.ToBeMocked(Cinput.class, Coutput.class, List.class)).
   andReturn(true);
```

In the scope of mocking, you should really be specifying the objects that you expect to be passed to that method, like:

```
Easymock.expect(MockClassObject.ToBeMocked(cInputObj, cOutputObj, listObj)).
   andReturn(true);
```

If for some reason you can't do that, you can use [`isA`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#isA-java.lang.Class-)/[`anyObject`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#anyObject-java.lang.Class-) variants:

```
Easymock.expect(MockClassObject.ToBeMocked(isA(Cinput.class), isA(Coutput.class), isA(List.class))).
   andReturn(true);
```

Comment: I tried that. It did not work for me.
Later I tried typecasting it.
'(List<CIOChain<Cinput, Coutput>>)easymock.anyobject();'

Comment: Total forgot this is in the scope of mocking! You should be using the `isA` variants if for some reason you can't expect the method call with the real/mock objects.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by "it did not work"? Did it fail due to wrong expectations? Did the mocking not happen?